# Probably syntax error with a PDO at the Class

Tags: php, class, pdo

I'm a new one at PHP and PDO and I've got stacked with probably very simple syntax error but I have no idea how to Google it right. I've tried many ways to make this but every time I have error at the same string. Is there any better way to get a PDO based request inside of a Class? I thought just to include the connection part as a separate file but still got the same error with $db variable.

```
class prepeared{
    private $_conn = "xxx"; //there is a real value here instead of "xxx"
    private $_user = "xxx";
    private $_pass = "xxx";
    private $_db;
    function __construct(){
        try{
        $this->_db = new PDO ($this->_conn, $this->_user, $this->_pass);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
        }
    }

    static function loginParams($login, $pass){
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT userid from users where login = ? AND pass = ?"); // <<<---- here comes en error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object..."
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $login, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindparam(2, $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row['userid'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$this` in a static context, which doesn't make sense.  Either remove `static` from the method declaration or make `$_db` `static` and change `$this->_db->prepare` in the method to `self::$_db->prepare`.  The first option is probably more appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Static functions can not use to `$this` as it `$this` refers to the instance of the class from which it is used. Static functions are called *statically* so they don't require a class instance, which is why you can't use `$this`